# HTML Video not working on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, video, html5-video

So I'm new to developing and have a basic knowledge of HTML and CSS, I'm attempting to code my personal website but I'm having trouble with videos on iPhone (It works fine on other phones).

I assume it's because I'm using the Autoplay feature, however I don't want to ruin the desktop experience of my site. Is it possible to keep the autoplay on desktop and still have the video in some capacity on iOS?

http://benca.in/tbgvfour.html

```
<div class="image1">
<video  autoplay="true" controls="true" autoplay loop class="video">
    <source src="assets/tbgv.mp4" type="video/webm">
    <source src="assets/tbgv.mov" type="video/mov">
    <source src="assets/tbgv.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Type of the first video is `video/mp4` not webm, and the .mov isn’t a native html5 video type

Answer (score 0):

There are truly some auto-play feature restrictions on iOS and Mac. But you can be informed by JavaScript promise construct whether the video was rejected or not and change it's behavior based on that.

You can use something like this:

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}
```

For more detailed information check this article:
https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/